# i am trying out nested resources and not working out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am getting this error

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#home
Showing C:/Users/jhakas realstate/Desktop/call/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #55 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"refills", :action=>"new"} missing required keys: [:user_id, :wallet_id]
Extracted source (around line #55):
52
53
54
55
56
57
58

```
         <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
         <% if user_signed_in? %>
           <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", new_user_wallet_refill_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
         <% else %>
```

and my resources in routes

```
resources :users do  
  resources :wallets do     
    resources :refills
  end
end
```

and my wallet controller is

```
def create
  @wallet = Wallet.new([:user_id]wallet_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @wallet.save
      format.html { redirect_to @wallet, notice: 'Wallet was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @wallet }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @wallet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines need the IDs of the parent resources to be able to work:

```
<li><%= link_to "Dashboard", new_user_wallet_refill_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
```

You should be using paths like this:

```
new_user_wallet_refill_path(@user, @wallet)
edit_user_registration_path(@user) # This one might not need the @user object ... I'm not a devise expert.
```

Comment: i did 'new_user_wallet_refill_path(@user, @wallet)' and i am getting ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#home

Comment: Do you have `@user` and `@wallet` instance variables though?

Comment: No how to do that and why

Comment: In your controller action for the view you're having trouble with, any instance variables (starting with an `@` sign) are available within your view. In your controller, set `@user = User.find(params[:id])` or however you're finding the user. Same with `@wallet` and everything should work.

Comment: Okay so I need to set instance variable in controller to access it in view. So if I have user controller I can create instance variable for other models and so forth?

Comment: Well, according to your error posted above, this is in the `home` action of your `Pages` controller?

Comment: Sorry I am noob and learning lol. Also if I have user has one wallet and wallet has many refills, wallet belongs to user and refills belongs to wallet, do I need to nest the resource? If yes why ? If no why? And when do we nest resource?

Comment: I need to know the instance variable question's answer too

Answer (score 0):

When you nest the wallet resource within the user resource I believe it breaks the redirect_to @wallet convention you used in the create method. Try using the actual path

```
redirect_to user_wallet_path(@wallet.user, @wallet)
```